# Идея функционального проектика

Tags: javascript

Прочитал очень много статей, и книгу (1000стр.) по JS. 
Хочется что-нибудь сделать для пополнения своего портфолио. 
Поделитесь идеей, которая станет для меня стартовой. 
Особый уклон на front-end и чистый JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knes просто монстр, думаю человек, который просто прочитал про js (1000 страниц, это наверное книга с носорогом, там же треть книги это справочник), маловато опыта для таких заданий, думаю лучше начать с имитации функций фреймворков jquery, prototype на чистом js. По верстке все просто, зайдите на любой сайт, который вам очень нравиться и который вы считаете вершиной веб строительства и сами повторите его верстку, естественно кроссбраузерно.

Comment: Человек просил для портфолио. =)

Comment: Да Вы првы) Носорог рулит)
Хочу щё с утко прочитать), Про шаблоны.
Насчёт фреймворка, хорошая идея) попробую)

Answer (score 3):

Пожалуйста:

1. Галерея с инерционной полосой. (Дергаем, отпускаем мышку - полоса продолжает некоторое время крутиться. Если сдвинули плавно, то только сдвиг.)
2. Ajax-меню с `location.hash`, которое перегенерит ссылку, чтобы можно было запомнить положение на сайте.
3. WYSIWYG редактор таблиц: добавление/удаление/перетаскивание строк/столбцов, прямоугольное выделение, изменение стилей, объединение ячеек. Короче то, для чего excel используют 99% пользователей.

Еще надо? =)

Comment: Конечно надо! Ваш свежий голова выдает прекрасные идеи.

Comment: 4) front-end файлового менеджера. Дерево папок и файлов можно брать из массива. А потом, когда разберетесь с php и ajax, сможете дописать файловый менеджер.

Comment: Спасибо) я знаю пхп и аякс)